# Перехват https ответа

Tags: c#, https

Не могу разобраться. У меня есть приложения arc welder (эмулятор android, использую для просмотра статей). Я хочу вытащить https ответ от него(готовый исходник статьи чтобы можно было работать с ним) при переходе например на одну статью, но не знаю как это сделать, нужен сниффер или что-то подобное?

Вот пример кода, где я написал что бы смотреть каждый пакет (так же работают сниферы?), но к сожалению поле "data" всегда пустое....

```
using PacketDotNet;
using SharpPcap;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // метод для получения списка устройств
            CaptureDeviceList deviceList = CaptureDeviceList.Instance;
            // выбираем первое устройство в спсике (для примера)
            ICaptureDevice captureDevice = deviceList[0];

            captureDevice.OnPacketArrival += new PacketArrivalEventHandler(Program_OnPacketArrival);

            captureDevice.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, 1000);
            // начинаем захват пакетов
            captureDevice.Capture();
        }
        static void Program_OnPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs e)
        {
            // парсинг всего пакета
            Packet packet = 
           Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType,e.Packet.Data);
            // получение только TCP пакета из всего фрейма
            var tcpPacket = TcpPacket.GetEncapsulated(packet);
            // получение только IP пакета из всего фрейма
            var ipPacket = IpPacket.GetEncapsulated(packet);
            if (tcpPacket != null && ipPacket != null)
            {
                DateTime time = e.Packet.Timeval.Date;
                int len = e.Packet.Data.Length;

                // IP адрес отправителя
                var srcIp = ipPacket.SourceAddress.ToString();
                // IP адрес получателя
                var dstIp = ipPacket.DestinationAddress.ToString();

                // порт отправителя
                var srcPort = tcpPacket.SourcePort.ToString();
                // порт получателя
                var dstPort = tcpPacket.DestinationPort.ToString();
                // данные пакета
                var data = tcpPacket.PayloadPacket;
                if(data != null)
                {
                    string a = "словил";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам нужен сниффер - берите Wireshark. Только толку будет мало: https вполне защищен от перехвата траффика. Используйте MitM

Comment: Ещё варианты есть?

Comment: Отладка приложения, но MitM значительно проще.

Comment: Хмммм, врятли такое захожу, подскажете сколько примерно будет стоять данная услуга?

Comment: @СерегаГасюк MitM - это не услуга (по крайней мере, не в IT)

Comment: @СерегаГасюк попробуйте взять отладчик https (fiddler, или что-то специфическое под андроид) и пропустить траффик через него. Тот же фиддлер поддерживает расшифровку https (подсовывая по дороге свои сертификаты, которые придется ставить на девайс / эмулятор)

Comment: @PashaPash когда я использую fiddler, приложения не грузит страницы

Comment: @СерегаГасюк потому что оно не доверяет сертификатам от фиддлера. их нужно вручную ставить на девайс

Comment: @PashaPash а как это сделать?

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForAndroid

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо! Немного помогли, посмотрел видео, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFJX8ETk2Mc, думаю всё сделаю, остался один вопрос, а как тот трафик что я получу можно будет обработать?